# how can I install Tomcat Manager without reinstalling Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-manager

OS: windows XP.

I already have a working Tomcat 7.0.25 installation and the folder "manager" is in the webapps folder.

I have read the documentation here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html
and is talking about already installed manager.

I have already set the **manager-gui** role to the user.

The problem is that if I access the manager using `http://localhost/manager`, I only get a white page (no content), if I try `https://localhost/manager`, I get a 404 error.

Any clue?

A link to download the manager application would also be useful.

Comment: update: I have removed the manager.xml file and now I do not get a 404 error anymore: I get a white page ragardless the fact that I connect with http or with https... with the manager.xml file, though, the Catalina.log contained a warning about docbase setting ignored.

Comment: why in the official documentation the codebase is written in the format `/usr/local/kinetic/tomcat7/server/webapps/manager`? is that for *nix users? what about our poor windows users?

Answer (score 2):

If you want access to the GUI, then you'll have to use the URL `http://localhost:8080/manager/html/`. There is nothing configured to respond to requests to `/` which is why you are seeing a blank screen. The URL required to use the Manager's GUI is clearly documented in the Manager's documentation on the Tomcat website.

Comment: nope. Did not work! blank page using http and 404 if using https.

Comment: Can you @Pierpaolo confirm that the manager webapp is actually deployed? Check `logs/catalina.out` during Tomcat startup to ensure that it is being deployed.

Comment: in Catalina.log i have `error: filterStart`, in manager.log I have `GRAVE: Exception starting filter SetCharacterEncoding
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter
`
the second error, however, occurs also in the other working application that I have in the same Tomcat server

Comment: Failing to start a filter should be catastrophic for the webapp, and it shouldn't start when that happens.

Comment: I know, but it was happening and the application was working anyway...
Menawhile, I have tried to copy the tomcat folder from the production server (I was working on my local copy) and now at least the application is asking for the credentials. Although I have set them in the users DB, I get a 500: `java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.authenticate(RealmBase.java:340)`

Comment: You are having a cascading series of failures that I have never seen before. At this point, I would suspect that you have trashed your configuration beyond the point where repair is possible except by an expert. My advice to you, now, it you reinstall Tomcat, make only the necessary changes to `tomcat-users.xml`, deploy the manager webapp and get it working. Only then should you reintroduce your own webapp into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the manager or the host-manager without reinstalling tomcat by simply copying the directories of the applications from the installation package to the `webapps` directory and settings the correct permisions.

```
chown -R tomcat:tomcat apache-tomcat-xx-yy/webapps/*
cp -r apache-tomcat-xx-yy/webapps/* $APACHE_HOME/webapps/
```

*Even if the questions is quite old and probably @Pierpaolo problem was different, I think it's usefull to share this info since it is a possible solution to the specific question of this thread.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have only one tomcat on your PC and that its port is 80 ?

By default the port is 8080 so the URL is `http://localhost:8080/manager`.

If you're sure tomcat is configured for the 80 port, check its log : You probably have another process (for example Apache httpd) listening on the 80 port and preventing its launch.

Comment: well, the manager is not the only application installed (which is why I do not want to reinstall tomcat) and the application is working fine.